# cargas masiva automatizada en mysq

Tags: mysql

Compañeros o colegas

Me pueden ayudar o darme una idea

tengo un archivo csv con n cantidad de registros que me llega cada hora, como puede realizar que cada vez que me llegue la informacion se carge de manera automatica a una tabla

Tengo este código para la carga masiva

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
 INFILE 'C:\\directory_example\\table.txt'
 INTO TABLE Table CHARACTER SET UTF8 
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Pero como puedo hacer o que función necesito para que lo corra cada hora y todos los días de la semana?

Answer (score 0):

Arriesgándome a que voten negativamente la respuesta, considero que vale la pena responder esta pregunta. Tarde o temprano todos nos veremos en este tipo de escenario.

En uno de mis trabajos anteriores, un proveedor externo subí a un archivo a un sitio ftp todos los días por la noche. 
A determinada hora, el servidor web, mediante una tarea programada, iniciaba un ejecutable (en nuestro caso, un servicio escrito en C#) que leía el último archivo añadido a esta carpeta.

Luego, si existía, lo procesaba (en tu caso, sería realizar la inserción en la base de datos utilizando los datos del archivo), y en una tabla de logs, insertaba la fecha, el nombre del archivo procesado, la descripción del proceso, errores (si hubo), líneas procesadas y un indicador de estado de procesamiento.

Este es un ejemplo, únicamente. Veamos qué otras recomendaciones tiene la comunidad.

Saludos

Comment: La idea es que, tanto pregunta como respuesta, lleven algo de código de ejemplo para hacer la cuestión algo más tangible, reproducible y que no se generen extensos debates... Estás entre programadores, nos gustan las cosas concretas :)

Comment: @DavidJP, llevas razón. Argumentaría que lo amplio de la pregunta, llamaba a una respuesta de la misma naturaleza. Sin embargo, llevas razón.

Comment: A mí me pasa mucho con las preguntas sobre modelado de datos, qué código se va a presentar si aún no se sabe ni cómo afrontar el problema... yo intento aportar algún diagrama ER, algo sobre lo que poder trabajar que al menos concrete un poco el problema :)

Answer (score 0):

Podes probar crear un [evento](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html#sa58173830)

[mysql event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)

```
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
    DO
     LOAD DATA LOCAL 
     INFILE 'C:\\directory_example\\table.txt'
     INTO TABLE Table CHARACTER SET UTF8 
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: me genera el LOAD DATA is not allowed in stored procedures

Comment: si me parecía que [habría algunas limitaciones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html). vas a tener que implementar un cron job o scheduler de windows

Comment: tendrás un ejemplo por qué el schedeler de Windows con un archivo bat y agregando la función load data local pero me genera error.

Comment: Que tipo de error? Pueden ser permisos de ejecución o que no encuentre el binario de mysql